# Python Request Post with param data

Tags: python, httprequest, python-requests, http-status-codes

This is the raw request for an API call:

```
POST http://192.168.3.45:8080/api/v2/event/log?sessionKey=b299d17b896417a7b18f46544d40adb734240cc2&format=json HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 86
Host: 192.168.3.45:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

{"eventType":"AAS_PORTAL_START","data":{"uid":"hfe3hf45huf33545","aid":"1","vid":"1"}}
```

This request returns a success (2xx) response.

Now I am trying to post this request using `requests`:

```
import requests

headers = {'content-type' : 'application/json'}
data ={"eventType" : "AAS_PORTAL_START", 
       "data" : {"uid": "hfe3hf45huf33545", 
                 "aid": "1", 
                 "vid": "1"}
      }
url = ("http://192.168.3.45:8080/api/v2/event/log?"
       "sessionKey=9ebbd0b25760557393a43064a92bae539d962103&"
       "format=xml&"
       "platformId=1")
requests.post(url, params=data, headers=headers)
```

The response from this request is

```
<Response [400]>
```

Everything looks fine to me and I am not quite sure what I posting wrong to get a 400 response.

Answer (score 435, accepted):

`params` is for GET-style URL parameters, `data` is for POST-style body information. It is perfectly legal to provide *both* types of information in a request, and your request does so too, but you encoded the URL parameters into the URL already.

Your raw post contains *JSON* data though. `requests` can handle JSON encoding for you, and it'll set the correct `Content-Type` header too; all you need to do is pass in the Python object to be encoded as JSON into the `json` keyword argument.

You could split out the URL parameters as well:

```
params = {'sessionKey': '9ebbd0b25760557393a43064a92bae539d962103', 'format': 'xml', 'platformId': 1}
```

then post your data with:

```
import requests

url = 'http://192.168.3.45:8080/api/v2/event/log'

data = {"eventType": "AAS_PORTAL_START", "data": {"uid": "hfe3hf45huf33545", "aid": "1", "vid": "1"}}
params = {'sessionKey': '9ebbd0b25760557393a43064a92bae539d962103', 'format': 'xml', 'platformId': 1}

requests.post(url, params=params, json=data)
```

The `json` keyword is new in `requests` version 2.4.2; if you still have to use an older version, encode the JSON manually using the `json` module and post the encoded result as the `data` key; you will have to explicitly set the Content-Type header in that case:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
url = 'http://192.168.3.45:8080/api/v2/event/log'

data = {"eventType": "AAS_PORTAL_START", "data": {"uid": "hfe3hf45huf33545", "aid": "1", "vid": "1"}}
params = {'sessionKey': '9ebbd0b25760557393a43064a92bae539d962103', 'format': 'xml', 'platformId': 1}

requests.post(url, params=params, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 14):

Assign the response to a value and test the attributes of it. These should tell you something useful.

```
response = requests.post(url,params=data,headers=headers)
response.status_code
response.text
```

- status_code should just reconfirm the code you were given before, of course

Comment: I tried that before and it says request id syntactically incorrect.

Comment: you probably mean
    `print(response.status_code)`
    `print(response.text)`

Answer (score 9):

Set data to this:

```
data ={"eventType":"AAS_PORTAL_START","data":{"uid":"hfe3hf45huf33545","aid":"1","vid":"1"}}
```

Comment: DO briefly explain what you have done differently from his data