# Http POST (multipart/form-data) via Python requests failed

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using Pythong requests lib to retrieve data from New Zealand Statistics website:
http://www.stats.govt.nz/infoshare/ExportDirect.aspx.
The http POST request is in format of "multipart/form-data". I googled and found that requests is 
a great library that supports multipart post.
However, my code didn't get the result that should be retrieved from the server.
Instead, It only gives me the source codes of website http://www.stats.govt.nz/infoshare/ExportDirect.aspx.

Can some one help me with this problem?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('http://www.stats.govt.nz/infoshare/ExportDirect.aspx')


soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
view_state = soup.find("input",id="__VIEWSTATE")["value"]
event_validation = soup.find("input",id="__EVENTVALIDATION")["value"]

post_data = {"__EVENTTARGET": "",
             "__EVENTARGUMENT": "",
             "__VIEWSTATE": view_state,
             "__EVENTVALIDATION": event_validation,
             "ctl00$MainContent$tbMissingText": "..",
             "ctl00$MainContent$TimeVariableSelector$tbSelected": "1",
             "ctl00$MainContent$TimeVariableSelector$lbVariableOptions": "0",
             "ctl00$MainContent$rblCSVFormat": "columns",
             "ctl00$MainContent$rblSeriesDescription": "no_description",
             "ctl00$MainContent$fuSearchFile": (open('Alcohol.sch'), 'application/octet-stream')
    }


r1 = requests.post('http://www.stats.govt.nz/infoshare/ExportDirect.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1', files = post_data)


print(r1.text)

input('Enter to exit...')
```

Comment: why do you do `soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('http://www.stats.govt.nz/infoshare/ExportDirect.aspx'))`? `soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)` will be enough here.

Comment: You can try the solution of [The answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15900453/1113211).

Comment: And also create the `soup` like this,
`soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)`
as you already have a `response` object `r`

Comment: Please, add example of file 'Alcohol.sch'.

Comment: The 'Alcohol.sch' file contains two IDs that are used to send requests to the server. The codes are: SEPQ.SBC3A 
SEPQ.SBC3B