# Microsoft Face API complaining about bad Key, but Key working in console?

Tags: python, face-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I been trying to solve this error but I can't find what seems to be wrong.

I am using `Microsoft Cognitive Services Face API` with `python`. Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json
import http.client, urllib, base64, json

body = {"URL": "http://www.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/35391452-5457-431A-A75B859471FAB0B3.jsdfpg" }

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "xxx"
}

try:

    r=requests.post('https://api.projectoxford.ai/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=false&returnFaceAttributes=age,gender',json.dumps(body) , headers)
    print(r.content)
except Exception as e:
    print(format(e))
```

When I run the script I get:

```
"code":"Unspecified","message":"Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure you are subscribed to an API you are trying to call and provide the right key."
```

The thing is that when I put the exact same Key on the [console](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236/console) everything works fine. So I am pretty sure it is not the key.

The error must be on my code, but I can't find it.

Any tip in the right direction will be appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in the way you conform the *request.post* call. Parameters to this function are positional, as mentioned in this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900338/python-request-post-with-param-data) hence the headers are not passed as headers, so the key is not recognized. If you specify what each parameter is, you will avoid this error. That is:

```
r=requests.post('https://api.projectoxford.ai/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=false&returnFaceAttributes=age,gender',params=None, data = json.dumps(body), headers = headers)
```

Also, the URL to your image does not point to a valid JPEG file (the extension is garbled, probably a typo).