# How do I post curl command as a python request?

Tags: python, python-requests, gitlab

```
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --data '{"path": "<subgroup_path>", "name": "<subgroup_name>", "parent_id": <parent_group_id> } \
  "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/groups/"
```

I was following the documentation from [gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html#new-subgroup). I just wanted to to know how to represent the part after `--data` as a python request. Will it be a part of `params`, `json` or any other parameter in requests module?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Here's the equivalent using `requests`:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    "PRIVATE-TOKEN": "<your_access_token>",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}
data = {
    "path": "<subgroup_path>",
    "name": "<subgroup_name>",
    "parent_id": "<parent_group_id>",
}

requests.post("https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/groups/",
    headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```

Answer (score 4):

It can be done by python's [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) package.

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/groups/"
headers = {'PRIVATE-TOKEN': '<your_access_token>', 'Content-Type':'application/json'}
data = {"path": "<subgroup_path>", "name": "<subgroup_name>", "parent_id": <parent_group_id>}

requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

reference : [Python Request Post with param data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900338/python-request-post-with-param-data)