# Why do I get error when simulating Ajax request with python

Tags: python, ajax, session, request

I am trying to simulate a web request using python library. This is the get request query created by the browser(I have replaced the actual url)

http://myurl.asp?treg=8338033&dob=14/09/2003&sid=0.3582164869592499

My code is here.

def individual(reg,dob):

```
session = Session()
myurl='http://myurl.asp'

# HEAD requests ask for *just* the headers, which is all you need to grab the
# session cookie
session.head('http://myurl')
response = session.get(
    url=myurl,
    data={
        'treg': reg,
        'dob': dob,
        'sid':'0.4443253265244038'
    },
    headers={
        'Referer': 'http://myurl.htm'
    }
)

return response.text
```

It gives me invalid date response from server. But the same values sent through browser is successful. I have already tried yyyy-mm-dd format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up GET-style params with POST ones by using `data` instead of `params` in the request `session.get` call.

[Python Request Post with param data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900338/python-request-post-with-param-data)