# How to pass variable into post request in Python

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I had created a simple python program to send Post Api request using request module

```
# importing the requests library 
import requests 
import json


headers = {
    'PRIVATE-TOKEN': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = '{ "ref": "cd-pipeline", "variables": [ {"key": "STAGE", "value": "CD"}, {"key": "DEPLOYMENT_STATUS", "value": "failed"} ] }'

response = requests.post('https://gitlab.kazan.atosworldline.com/api/v4/projects/28427/pipeline', headers=headers, data=data)
print(response)
```

However, I wish to replace the below string to use a variable

```
"value": "failed"
```

something to below

```
"value": deployment_status
```

Comment: Create a Python dictionary instead of the JSON and pass it as the `json=` argument to `requests.post()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Request Post with param data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900338/python-request-post-with-param-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass json data to your API, you can directly use the json attribute of the `request.post()` function with a dictionary variable.

Example:

```py
# importing the requests library 
import requests 


headers = {
    'PRIVATE-TOKEN': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
deployment_status = "failed"
data = { "ref": "cd-pipeline", "variables": [ {"key": "STAGE", "value": "CD"}, {"key": "DEPLOYMENT_STATUS", "value": deployment_status} ] }

response = requests.post('https://gitlab.kazan.atosworldline.com/api/v4/projects/28427/pipeline', headers=headers, json=data)
print(response)
```

Comment: This Code work for me..Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recent version of python you can use f-strings:

```py
deployment_status = 'failed'
data = f'{ "ref": "cd-pipeline", "variables": [ {"key": "STAGE", "value": "CD"}, {"key": "DEPLOYMENT_STATUS", "value": "{deployment_status}"} ] }'
```

**Update:**

Ok, so that turned out to be too deeply nested for f-strings.

Better just to use `json`:

```py
import json

deployment_status = 'failed'
data = {"ref": "cd-pipeline", "variables": [ {"key": "STAGE", "value": "CD"}, {"key": "DEPLOYMENT_STATUS", "value": deployment_status} ] }

print(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: make sure you have python version >3.6, if you are going to use this code

Comment: This gives me `SyntaxError: f-string: expressions nested too deeply` on Python 3.7

Comment: This code works for me..thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use an "f-string" to format the value of the variable into your data string.

*Example*

```
deployment_status = 'status'
data = f'{ "ref": "cd-pipeline", "variables": [ {"key": "STAGE", "value": "CD"}, {"key": "DEPLOYMENT_STATUS", "value": "{deployment_status}"} ] }'
```

Comment: this code give below "SyntaxError: f-string: expressions nested too deeply"