# Python requests: response.request.body property is null after a POST

Tags: python, rest, http, post, python-requests

I am trying to debug a POST request which returns 400 using [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) library.

The request is of type:

```
POST https://somesite.com/path?key=value
{
  "some": "payload"
}
```

So it has both query parameters and body.

Inspecting the `response.request` object I can see that the `body` property is null so the problem could be I am passing the arguments in the wrong way, but I couldn't figure out where the issue is.

```py
import requests
import json


session = requests.Session()

response = session.request(
    url='https://somesite.com/path?key=value',
    method='POST',
    headers={
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    json={
        'some': 'payload',
    }
)

print(response.status_code)  # 400
print(response.request.body)  # null
```

Following [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900338/python-request-post-with-param-data), I've also tried to extract the query parameters from the url and pass them using `params` in the request, but still no luck (400 and `response.request.body=null`):

```py
import requests
import json


session = requests.Session()

response = session.request(
    url='https://somesite.com/path',
    method='POST',
    headers={
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    params={'key': 'value'},
    json={
        'some': 'payload',
    }
)

print(response.status_code)  # 400
print(response.request.body)  # null
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to change method session.request argument json to data

Comment: already tried, same result unfortunately

Comment: try to use curl to check http api, make sure the request is OK, command: curl -X POST https://somesite.com/path?key=value
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
     -d "{\"some\":\"payload\"}"