# How to connect to a CRM and download data from it?

Tags: python, json, api

Would like to ask how to connect to CRM. I seem to have everything but do not know how to do it.It wants to connect using python. I have: "clientId", "apiKey", "requestTime", "sha", everything that CRM Salesmanago requires.
How can I connect? On their website it is written like this:

> Each API call, except for authentication, has to include authentication data.
> Values of clientId can be found under the "Integration" bookmark in the "Settings" menu. The apiKey value is a random string used for authentication.

Link to the [Salesmanago API Reference](http://docs.salesmanago.com/). I want to download data from this CRM.

```
{
  "clientId":"your-client-id-123",
  "apiKey":"your-api-key-123",
  "requestTime":1327056031488,
  "sha":"2aa3927a7dee8c2a712adb5375f5fa36dd8fe00c"
}
```

Comment: Did you hear of `requests` library?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900338/python-request-post-with-param-data you are going to have to send headers as well according to the documentation that you linked (the required headers are in the docs as well)

Comment: Yes I have heard of requests, but I still don't know how to do it. 
But thanks for trying to help.