# Setting PHP $_POST from Python

Tags: python, php, post, python-requests

I would like to interact with a website written in PHP using Python. It pulls its data from a form with method `POST`.
Now I have tried to set the values in `$_POST` by doing:

```
url = 'https://www.example.com/myscript.php'

data = {"PcID":"AJFJ-01AR","email":"email","refc":"","startBtn":"Start"}

result = requests.post(url, json=data).content
```

But I am sadly unable to set the values PHP receives with this (I am returned the page with form instead of after, meaning not all values are set). The `data` variable is copy-pasted from what PHP receives using the form on the website (`echo json_encode($_POST);`). Am I generally wrong in what I am doing? It wouldn't be hard for me to just give the values with a regular `GET` request but I am still wondering why this would not work.
Thank you!

Comment: You want `data=data`, not `json=data`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that! From this post I understood that it would be `json=data`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900338/python-request-post-with-param-data

Comment: *If* you want to send JSON data. But PHP doesn't parse JSON data into `$_POST`, only percent-encoded requests (the default for HTML forms).

Answer (score 0):

The comment by deceze fixed it (thank you!). It should be `result = requests.post(url, data=data).content` not `result = requests.post(url, json=data).content`.