# [Python]Query http request

Tags: python

How to query id from the url? I want to get id from request so I tried this but it doesn't work.

My request url:http://localhost:8888/api/genshin?id=119480035 then it gives me 404.I expect it can query the id instead of 404

```
def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == "/api/genshin":
            # request url example: /api/genshin?id=119480035
            id = self.path.split("=")[1]
            data = asyncio.run(main(id))
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(bytes(json.dumps(data), "utf-8"))
        else:
            self.send_response(404)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(bytes("<h1>404 Not Found</h1>", "utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are apparently using [`BaseHTTPRequestHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/http.server.html#http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler), where the documentation says

> `path` contains the request path. **If query component of the URL is present, then path includes the query.**

(emphasis mine), which is why the `if` statement doesn't match if it has a query.

You'd need to split `self.path` so you only get the path and the query to match them. It's easy to do with `urlparse`; you can also use `parse_qsl` to parse the query parameters:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qsl

# ...

def do_GET(self):
    parsed = urlparse(f"http://fake{self.path}")
    path = parsed.path
    query = dict(parse_qsl(parsed.query))
    if path == "/api/genshin":
        id = query.get("id")
    # ...
```

However, all in all you might want to look at a higher-level mini web framework such as Flask.

Answer (score -1):

?id=119480035 is query parameter, you need to pass it when making the request, and depends on it's a GET or POST request, it's different to pass.

For example:
[Python Request Post with param data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900338/python-request-post-with-param-data)