# Pinterst api: not able to get access token - Stuck in Oauth flow

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, python-requests, pinterest

Using v5 of the pinterest api and stuck on the authentication flow: https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/getting-started/authentication/

Completed the first step and got the access code.
However, I get the below error when I try to use this code to get the access token.

`{"code":1,"message":"Missing request body"}`

Here is my code:

```
client_id= 'my_client_id'
client_secret = 'my_client_secret'

data_string = f'{client_id}:{client_secret}'

token = base64.b64encode(data_string.encode())

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8'),
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}

url = "https://api.pinterest.com/v5/oauth/token"
code = "my_code_that_i_got_in_the_first_step"

params = {
    'grant_type':'authorization_code',
    'code': code,
    'redirect_url':'https://my_redirect_uri'
}
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, params=params)
print(r.json())
```

Comment: You want to send that as data, not params.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900338/python-request-post-with-param-data

Comment: Sending it as data is giving me a new error: `{'code': 1, 'message': 'Invalid parameters.'}`.  I changed the `params` to `data` in the POST request.

Comment: Nevermind. There was a typo. Used redirect_url instead of uri ... smh... thanks for the tip on sending it as data @AmosBaker

Answer (score 1):

Below is the correct way to get the access token:

```
client_id= 'my_client_id'
client_secret = 'my_client_secret'

data_string = f'{client_id}:{client_secret}'

token = base64.b64encode(data_string.encode())

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + token.decode('utf-8'),
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}

url = "https://api.pinterest.com/v5/oauth/token"
code = "my_code_that_i_got_in_the_first_step"

data= {
    'grant_type':'authorization_code',
    'code': code,
    'redirect_uri':'https://my_redirect_uri'
}
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
print(r.json())
```

In my question, I had mistyped redirect_uri as redirect_url. Also, when sending a POST, you should use data instead of params. See the comment by Amos Baker.