# How to pass a parameter to the payload in a URL request (python)

Tags: python, string, url, python-requests, payload

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgoMx.jpg)
I want to be able to pass a variable through to where the registration plate (AA19AAA) is

Overall, I want a function to check the number plate, therefore I need to pass a parameter through the function and use it in the payload, but I'm not sure how to actually pass a string to the inside of the payload.

I have tried using .format(...) to add things to the string, concatenating the variable into the payload, and another method similar to .format(...). However, if you believe any of these could be applicable, please don't hesitate to tell me as I may have made a mistake somewhere.

I hope some of you can assist me in this, I'm sorry if there is an incredibly simple solution to this, but I have tried a few, and feel that it is time to ask the professionals.
Thank you so much

Comment: Please [don't post code/errors/data as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is exactly? The image shows some code that has the rego in  there, are you asking how you can create a template that allows you to call the web service with varying license plate numbers? You say you tried `.format()`, can you share what you tried and explain what happened, and what you expected/wanted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Request Post with param data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900338/python-request-post-with-param-data)

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options:

```
import requests
import json
payload = {'registrationNumber': some_var}
headers = {..., 'content': 'application/json'}
result = requests.post(url, headers = headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

or

```
import requests
headers = {...}
payload = {'registrationNumber': some_var}
result = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
```